# How to show a small clickable item on Android map

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm working on maps on Android. I create at runtime overlays and, when clicked, I show a dialog that, when clicked, goes to a new activity. I don't like so much the dialog so I would like to show a smaller clickable object (like in foursquare or in photos application for iPhone). Has anyone done something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create custom overlays for map annotations.

[here is some code from github](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons)